# Laravel paginate() not returning results of nested relationship if limit is applied

Tags: php, laravel

While using nested relationships & applying a limit, the results returned by `paginate(10)` function are incorrect.

```
$products = Products::with(['customers' => function ($query) {
    $query->active();
}])
    ->paginate(10);
```

This piece of code returns the following data:

```
Array
(
    [current_page] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [description] => Sample Product Name
                    [created_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                    [customers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 15
                                    [product_id] => 1
                                    [customer_id] => 84
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                                    [updated_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 16
                                    [product_id] => 1
                                    [customer_id] => 86
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                                    [updated_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [description] => Sample Product Name
                    [created_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                    [customers] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

Which is correct. However, if I apply a limit to the results of `customers`, like such:

```
$products = Products::with(['customers' => function ($query) {
    $query->active()->limit(5);
}])
    ->paginate(10);
```

Suddenly the results are gone.

```
Array
(
    [current_page] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [description] => Sample Product Name
                    [created_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                    [customers] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [description] => Sample Product Name
                    [created_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2022-10-04T17:05:25.000000Z
                    [customers] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Laravel docs:

> **The `limit` and `take` query builder methods may not be used when
> constraining eager loads.**

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: I think i've used in the past and worked great. Well, anyway..thanks.